# Android Studio only recognising 1.6 JDK when 1.8 installed?

Tags: java, android

I am learning to build an Android app for the first time, and not even able to get past the set up stage!!

I am using a Mac on OS X 10.9.5. I have the latest version of Android Studio (2.1.2) and JDK/JRE 1.6 and 1.8 installed on my machine.

When I go to Android Studio > About Android Studio, it tells me the JRE is 1.6.

I'm also getting an error saying: "Rendering Problems Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later Install a supported JDK"

I have JDK v1.8 installed.

In File > Project Structure > SDK Manager I have the following set:

Android SDK Location =

```
/Users/Tom/Library/Android/sdk
```

Android JDK Location =

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I enter

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

it displays the following:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home
```

When I enter

```
echo $JDK_HOME
```

it also displays the following:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Why is Android Studio not recognising the 1.8 JDK?? Have been googling for 3hrs and getting nowhere. Any advice hugely recommended.

Comment: post your android studio project structure screenshot and android studio error screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Just move your default Android Studio JRE, in this case to move JDK 1.6.0, on OSX do this

`sudo mv /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk /tmp`

Then restart your Android Studio, and check "About Android Studio"